# How to implement Mat-radio-button autofocus

Tags: angular, angular-material

I tried to implement `mat-radio-button` autofocus, but I am not able to implement this. I tried with `Viewchild`, `Viewchildren` and `document.queryselector("#testid").focus()`.

Here is my sample radiobutton code:

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="site" id="test_{{i}}" role="radiogroup" #radioButtons *ngFor="let site of paginatedSites; let i = index;">
   <mat-radio-button [value]="site" role="radio" title="{{ site.name}} {{ site.customerSiteName }}" (keydown.enter)="changeContactType(site)">
         {{ site.name }}
    </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for providing your code, but what would you like us to do? Doesn't this code work, are the results incorrect, should it be extended ...? Please read [answer] and [mcve], then [edit] the your post to include a question about this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 setTimeout(() => {
  if (this.radioButtons && this.radioButtons.first) {
    // Focus the first radio button
    const firstRadioButton = this.radioButtons.first.nativeElement.querySelector('.mat-radio-button');
    if (firstRadioButton) {
      firstRadioButton.focus();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. I tried with your answer. But its not working.

Comment: Finally I found the solution by using viewchild decorator.

**code** 
HTML:
<mat-radio-group #radioButtons >
   <mat-radio-button [value]="site" role="radio">
         {{ site.name }}
    </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>

<button class="hyperButtonLink" role="Link" aria-label="Focus Button" tabindex="1" (focusout)="focusAutoCheck()">Download CSV</button>

Typescript:

@ViewChild('radioButtons') radioButtons: MatRadioButton;
focusAutoCheck() {
    if(this.radioButtons){ 
    this.radioButtons.focus();
    }
  }